# installed ubuntu-desktop on ubbuntu server AND: startx requires sudo startx

Tags: server, 18.04, xorg, gdm

sudo startx will work, but startx will not.

I can see the .Xauthority file in the root directory, but man says it should be located in /run/gdm

I know the problem has something to do with permissions and the location of the file, but I can't find where to change configuration of the default to be NOT in the // directory.  I am going to try adding setting in the custom.conf file with a document I found on x.org

:/$ startx

xauth: timeout in locking authority file //.Xauthority

(EE)

Fatal server error:

(EE) Cannot open log file "//.local/share/xorg/xorg.0.log"

(EE)

(EE)

Please consult the The X.org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help

(EE)

xinit: giving up

xinit unalble to connect to X server: Connection refused

xinit: server error

xauth:  timeout in locking authority file //.xauthority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the problem was related to .xauthority being in // which is not accessible by a normal user.  I never found where the "default" setting was located, but thought about why it might be there when it is not supposed to be, and I did not specifically point it there.

I began to think about what was different that might cause the issue.  So although I had followed what I thought was a careful explanation for changing my user name and home directory, I skipped a step... setting my new home directory with usermod.

So, sure enough when I examined $HOME, it was looking at my old directory with the username that no longer existed as I had changed the directory name to match my new user name.

Once I corrected that issue.  All works as it should.